# Fos elastica : update ES data on nested object

Tags: symfony, object, nested, foselasticabundle

I work on a Symfony2 project with fos:elastica. Users can like and following places they like. By default, when a user like a place we automatically add the "following" action.

So first of all, i persist these 2 actions in database (doctrine2). My datas are correctly saved in db.

When i make an ES query with the index "user_action" i get all actions related to a place (previous like & following).

But when i do the same with the index "place" i only get the first action (like).

It seems ES don't manage to update userAction in suggestion object.

On the other side, if i remove the query which persist a "following" action (added automatically after a like) and i do a second call (via an api) my action is saved in db and also updated in place object.

Hope someone will understand what i said and i what i try to do ^^

## Mapping

### Place

```
place:
     mappings:
      id:
       type: integer
      userAction:
       type: nested
       properties:
         userId:
           type: integer
         userActionTypeId:
           type: integer
         userActionType:
           type: nested
           properties:
             name:
               type: string
```

### User action

```
user_action:
    mappings:
          userId:
            type: integer
          placeId: ~
          place:
            type: nested
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
          userActionType:
            type: nested
            properties:
              name: ~
```

## Listener

### Service

```
`fos_elastica.listener.place.user_action`:
   class: API\Rest\v1\PlaceBundle\EventListener\ElasticaUserActionListener
   arguments:
       - @fos_elastica.object_persister.search.user_action
       - ['postPersist', 'postRemove']
       - @fos_elastica.indexable
   calls:
       - [ setContainer, ['@service_container', @fos_elastica.object_persister.search.place ] ]
   tags:
       - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

### Class

```
<?php

namespace API\Rest\v1\PlaceBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener as BaseListener;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use API\Rest\v1\UserActionBundle\Entity\UserAction;

class ElasticaUserActionListener extends BaseListener
{
    private $container;
    private $objectPersisterSuggestion;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container, ObjectPersister $objectPersisterSuggestion)
    {
        $this->container                 = $container;
        $this->objectPersisterPlace = $objectPersisterPlace;
    }

    public function postPersist(EventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof UserAction) {
            $this->scheduledForInsertion[] = $entity;
            $this->objectPersisterPlace->replaceOne($entity->getPlace());
        }
    }

    public function postRemove(EventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof UserAction) {
            $this->scheduleForDeletion($entity);
            $this->objectPersisterPlace->replaceOne($entity->getPlace());
        }
    }
}
```

## Current result

### Get place (#320) with nested object userAction

```
query : http://localhost:9200/search/place/_search
"hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "search",
        "_type" : "place",
        "_id" : "320",
        "_score" : 5.7004805,
        "_source":{
            "userAction":[
                {
                    "userActionType":{
                        "name":"like"
                    },
                    "userActionTypeId":3,
                    "userId":3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

### Get user Action related to place with id #320

```
query : http://localhost:9200/search/user_action/_search
"hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "search",
        "_type" : "user_action",
        "_id" : "50",
        "_score" : 5.7004805,
        "_source" : {
            "userId" : 4,
            "placeId" : 320,
            "userActionType" : {
                "name" : "following"
                }
            }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "search",
        "_type" : "user_action",
        "_id" : "49",
        "_score" : 5.402646,
        "_source" : {
            "userId" : 4,
            "placeId" : 320,
            "userActionType" : {
                "name" : "like"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

## UPDATE (solution)

I finally find the right way to do it. I was flushing datas too soon.

I replaced this wrong code

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($like);
$em->flush();  

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($following);
$em->flush();
```

by

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($like);
$em->persist($following);  
$em->flush();
```

and it's working!!!!

Hope this could help someone.

Comment: You could use Symfony's profiler to check what ES queries are made during particular Symfony's requests. That should help you to find out what's going on here.

Comment: I juste updated my post with the solution. I saw your advice too late. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

What works well for me with FOSElasticaBundle 3.0.x to update nested objects generally in is the following:

Add this to `app/config/config.yml`

```
services:
    # your other services

    fos_elastica.listener.search.user_action:
        class: "Acme\Bundle\UserActionBundle\EventListener\ElasticaUserActionListener"
        arguments:
            - @fos_elastica.object_persister.search.user_action
            - ['postPersist', 'postInsert', 'postUpdate', 'preRemove']
            - @fos_elastica.indexable
            - { indexName: 'user_action', typeName: 'userAction'}
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, ['@service_container', @fos_elastica.object_persister.search.user_action] ]
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

Then create a new file in `UserActionBundle\EventListener`:

```
# Acme\Bundle\UserActionBundle\EventListener\ElasticaUserActionListener.php
namespace Acme\Bundle\UserActionBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener as BaseListener;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class ElasticaUserActionListener extends BaseListener
{
    private $container;
    private $objectPersisterUserAction;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container, ObjectPersister $objectPersisterUserAction)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->objectPersisterUserAction = $objectPersisterUserAction;
    }

    public function getClassAccessorArray() {
        return [
            [
                'accessor' => 'getPlace', 
                'class' => new Place(),
            ],
            // add more child objects here, if needed
        ];
    }

    public function postPersist(EventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        foreach ($this->getClassAccessorArray() as $accessorArray) {
            $class = $accessorArray['class'];
            $accessorFunction = $accessorArray['accessor'];
            if ($entity instanceof $class) {
                $this->scheduledForInsertion[] = $entity;
                $this->objectPersisterUserAction->insertOne($entity->$accessorFunction());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function postUpdate(EventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        foreach ($this->getClassAccessorArray() as $accessorArray) {
            $class = $accessorArray['class'];
            $accessorFunction = $accessorArray['accessor'];
            if ($entity instanceof $class) {
                $this->scheduledForUpdate[] = $entity;
                $this->objectPersisterUserAction->replaceOne($entity->$accessorFunction());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function preRemove(EventArgs $eventArgs) {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        foreach ($this->getClassAccessorArray() as $accessorArray) {
            $class = $accessorArray['class'];
            $accessorFunction = $accessorArray['accessor'];

            if ($entity instanceof $class) {
                $this->scheduleForDeletion($entity);
                $this->objectPersisterUserAction->deleteOne($entity->$accessorFunction());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well to update ElasticSearch's index when directly updating nested objects. In your case, as you have effectively a bidirectional relationship between `Place`s and `UserAction`s, you might either extend the Listener class to handle both classes, or just duplicate and create a `ElasticaPlaceListener` service and class as well.